# Error in a nested IF statement

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, statements

I am trying to pull the daily schedule for each person on my team at work from another tab that has their schedule for the month so I can see who's working that day next to other stats I need to track for each person. To do this I am trying to write a nested IF statement but it isn't working and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

What I have so far:

`=IF(AQ1="1-May",IF(AQ1="2-May",IF(AQ1="3-May",IF(AQ1="4-May",IF(AQ1="5-May",Schedules!B5,Schedules!D5,Schedules!F5,Schedules!H5),Schedules!J5),"")`

But I just keep getting:

> "You have too many arguments for this function"

And I haven't even added all the arguments I need yet (there will be 14 in total).

I know I am probably doing something very wrong, I just can't figure out what, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close the parentheses in the correct order:

`=IF(AQ1="1-May",IF(AQ1="2-May",IF(AQ1="3-May",IF(AQ1="4-May",IF(AQ1="5-May",Schedules!B5,Schedules!D5),Schedules!F5),Schedules!H5),Schedules!J5),"")`

Comment: Thanks that fixed the issue with the too many arguments error but I have a new problem, now the only value that returns anything is if the first statement is true. Here's the updated string (had to change the date format as using dates seemed to also cause issues):

=IF($AQ$1="May 1st",IF($AQ$1="May 2nd",IF($AQ$1="May 3rd",IF($AQ$1="May 4th",IF($AQ$1="May 5th",Schedules!J5,Schedules!H5),Schedules!F5),Schedules!D5),Schedules!B5),"")

Comment: You should ask a new question if you have a new problem. Also you could research `VLOOKUP`

Comment: ok will do, I would use vlookup but its not grabbing data from a single column so it won't work.